# Textbook example integration

Tags: calculus

I am really struggling understanding how you could just substitute i for n. Could someone explain how this is possible? I do not see the logic at this exact step. Every thing after and before I get, just not how the i pointed out by the red arrow could be changed from n.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion is that $x_n=\frac {2n}{n}$.  However this is just the last term in the sequence:

$$x_0=\frac{2\cdot 0}{n},x_1=\frac {2\cdot 1}{n}, x_2=\frac {2\cdot 2}{n}, x_3=\frac {2\cdot 3}{n}, \cdots, x_i=\frac {2\cdot i}{n} , \cdots,  x_n=\frac {2\cdot n}{n}$$

$$\left\{x_i\;\middle|\; i\in\{0..n\}, x_i=\dfrac{2i}n\right\}$$

Comment: Thats what I thought, but sometimes I make my own conclusions and when they are wrong it usually creates more frustration later one. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is that $x_i + 1 = \frac{2i}{n} + 1$, which is the same as $x_i = \frac{2i}{n}$. That follows from the pattern in the line of displayed values of $x_i$ just above, where you see that 
$$
x_0 = 0,
$$
which is the same as 
$$
\frac{2\cdot 0}{n},
$$
and 
$$
x_1 = \frac{2}{n},
$$
which is the same as 
$$
\frac{2\cdot 1}{n},
$$
and
$$
x_2 = \frac{4}{n},
$$
which is the same as 
$$
\frac{2\cdot 2}{n},
$$
and so on.